# What's the simplest way to use SSE with Redis pub/sub and Akka Streams?

Tags: scala, redis, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'd like to stream a chunked server sent event for the following scenario:

Subscribe to a Redis key, and if the key changes, stream the new value with Akka Streams. It should only stream if there are new values.

As I understand it, I need a `Source`. I guess that is the subscription to a channel:

```
redis.subscriber.subscribe("My Channel") {
  case message @ PubSubMessage.Message(channel, messageBytes) => println(
    message.readAs[String]()
  )
  case PubSubMessage.Subscribe(channel, subscribedChannelsCount) => println(
    s"Successfully subscribed to $channel"
  )
}
```

In my route I need to create a `Source` from this, but honestly I don't know how to get going:

```
val route: Route =
  path("stream") {
   get {
     complete {
       val source: Source[ServerSentEvent, NotUsed] =
         Source
          .asSubscriber(??) // or fromPublisher???
      .map(_ => {
        ??
      })
      .map(toServerSentEvent)
      .keepAlive(1.second, () => ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
      .log("stream")
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use [`Source.actorRef`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#actorRef[T](bufferSize:Int,overflowStrategy:akka.stream.OverflowStrategy):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.actor.ActorRef]) and [`BroadcastHub.sink`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/BroadcastHub$.html#sink[T]:akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[T,akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed]]):

```
val (sseActor, sseSource) =
  Source.actorRef[String](10, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
    .map(toServerSentEvent) // converts a String to a ServerSentEvent
    .keepAlive(1.second, () => ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
    .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[ServerSentEvent])(Keep.both)
    .run()
```

Subscribe the materialized `ActorRef` to your message channel: messages sent to this actor are emitted downstream. If there is no downstream demand, the messages are buffered up to a certain number (in this example, the buffer size is 10) with the specified overflow strategy. Note that there is no backpressure with this approach.

```
redis.subscriber.subscribe("My Channel") {
  case message @ PubSubMessage.Message(channel, messageBytes) =>
    val strMsg = message.readAs[String]
    println(strMsg)
    sseActor ! strMsg

  case ...
}
```

Also note that the above example uses a `Source.actorRef[String]`; adjust the type and the example as you see fit (for example, it could be `Source.actorRef[PubSubMessage.Message]`).

And you can use the materialized `Source` in your path:

```
path("stream") {
  get {
    complete(sseSource)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! It works like a charm. But in the log I'm now seeing this: `Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received... Note that the connection will be closed after this response. Also, many clients will not read early responses! Consider only issuing this response after the request data has been completely read!` It's probably because in `subscribe` I'm pushing out the initial state of my object for the clients to set. Any ideas to prevent it?

Comment: thank you for this, works fine for me. any chance on how to change the event type name? currently it is `message`..

Comment: How do you handle disconnections? Redis subscription is still active when the client close the connection and your actor will continue to process messages, even if no one will consume them

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach could be to create a Source as queue and offer the element to the queue as received in the subscriber callback

```
val queue =
  Source
    .queue[String](10, OverflowStrategy.dropHead) // drops the oldest element from the buffer to make space for the new element.
    .map(toServerSentEvent) // converts a String to a ServerSentEvent
    .keepAlive(1.second, () => ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
    .to(Sink.ignore)
    .run()
```

and in the subscriber

```
    redis.subscriber.subscribe("My Channel") {
  case message @ PubSubMessage.Message(channel, messageBytes) =>
    val strMsg = message.readAs[String]
    println(strMsg)
    queue.offer(strMsg)

  case ...
}
```